# Can I use a base class method to enable a variety of ui controls in .net?

Tags: .net, forms, controls

I need to write a delegate for a worker thread that will handle a wide variety of form controls (buttons, textbox, list...) enable method. I'm thinking they must all be derived from a base class that handles the enable property, but I'm not finding any documentation, nor am I sure how to call the method.

Answer (score 1):

MSDN is the place to be for this type of info:

[System.Windows.Forms.Control.Enabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enabled.aspx)